# Is that noise real?

Tags: fringe

In fringe, when the Observers try to 'read people', we can hear a high pitched noise.

**Is this noise real?** (meaning it is heard by people 'in the room')
**Or is it some mechanism that is supposed to allow us** (the viewers) **to understand that they are 'reading people'?**

Comment: It would be interesting if the noise was at 6955hz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This noise does not appear to be real as it was never previously seen when September read the team or anyone else in the first few seasons, or when August read the girl he rescued from the plane crash.

It seems to be have added recently to help us notice when the Observer is trying to read someone.